# Async/await and conditional compilation

Tags: .net, vb.net, async-await, code-reuse, conditional-compilation

I'm writing a shared code library which will be used in

- a shiny new portable class library for mobile devices and
- a legacy project using .NET 3.5.

Thus, my code contains a lot of those:

```
#If PCL Then
    Await AlertAsync("...some message...", "...some title...")
#Else
    MessageBox.Show("...some message...", "...some title...")
#End If
```

which is repetitive and, thus, ugly.

Usually, if something is repetitive, the solution is to extract it to a method. Unfortunately, I don't see how to do this here since (1) I *must* use `await` to call the method in the PCL case and (2) I *must not* use `await` in .NET 3.5, since the compiler can't handle it. I'd *love* to have something like that:

```
AwaitIfNet45OrHigher ShowAlert("...some message...", "...some title...")

...

#If PCL Then
    Private Async Function ShowAlert(...) As Task
        ...async implementation...
    End Sub
#Else
    Private Sub ShowAlert(...)
        ....NET 3.5 implementation...
    End Sub
#End If
```

But, alas, there is no `AwaitIfNet45OrHigher` keyword in the VB.NET language.

Any other solution that I've missed (apart from resorting to T4 macros)?

Comment: Why not have two methods, ShowAlert and ShowAlertAsync and don't compile the second for 3.5?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: That's basically what I have right now (just mentally replace MessageBox.Show with ShowAlert and AlertAsync with ShowAlertAsync in the first code example). I still need 5 lines of code and mention every parameter twice. I'd like one line of code and mention every parameter once. :-)

Comment: You could put Else and EndIf after the method name but before the parameters.

Comment: If you're writing a library, can you not leave "display an alert to the user and wait for them to acknowledge it" as a callback/event that your consumers have to supply? And that way you're not tied into specific UI technologies (such as `MessageBox`) which means that your library may be more broadly applicable as well.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Sure, I can do that. Still, the original problem remains: I need to call the callback with `await` in .NET 4.5 and without await in .NET 3.5.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: That would be great, but, unfortunately, `#Else` and `#End If` must be on their own line and line continuations are eliminated (probably by the parser) *before* conditional comments are evaulated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AsyncBridge](http://omermor.github.io/AsyncBridge/), you just need to add a file to your project for await / async to work in .NET 4.0 / 3.5.

Comment: The link you provided only talks about .NET 4.0, not .NET 3.5.

Comment: [AsyncBridge on NuGet for .NET 3.5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncBridge.Net35/)

Answer (score -2):

As a general rule of thumb Conditional Compile Symbols should never be used.
An exception might be "#if DEBUG"

But for things like this, especially like this. You need to step back and follow proper .Net Library Architecture.

The two things might look like the same, but they are completely different.
You need to create a new library for .NET 4.5
-yes you will have two versions of the project for a while as you pull in the items

but cleaner files will save you so much time in the long run.
Not to mention .net 3.5 is on it's way out the door.
plus there are a whole bunch of really awesome features added in 4.5. Maybe it's time to rework the library completely to get the latest and greatest features.

To add on, a processor upgrade rewrite can be done peacemill. Rewrite only the functions you need now in a versioned project and reference them both in the portable library.